# Is there a simple way to see all the enhancements in a JDK version?

Tags: java

I can see the list of JEPs on the OpenJDK website but I think there are smaller API enhancements - new methods added etc. Is there a complete list of such changes or would I have to go through each GitHub tag to see them?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Java Version Almanac to compare Java versions and get a list of changes.

https://javaalmanac.io/

For example if you want to know what methods are added or removed between Java 18 and 19:
https://javaalmanac.io/jdk/19/apidiff/18/

Comment: Incredible - exactly what I needed. Thnx

Comment: This is indeed very nice

Answer (score 1):

Though not quite as comprehensive as [javaalmanac.io](https://javaalmanac.io/) as detailed in [the answer from mszalbach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71268131/2985643), the formal Javadoc documentation for each JDK release now details all API changes since JDK 11.

To access details of changes, just click **New** on the Javadoc menu bar. For example, if you [do that for JDK 18](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/new-list.html) this is what you see:

[image: JDK changes 1]

There is a series of links listed under **Contents** for changes made to classes, methods, packages, etc. You can drill down by clicking any of those links. For example, by [clicking the methods link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/new-list.html#method), then scrolling down to **java.lang.String** you can see all methods added to the `String` class since JDK 11:

[image: JDK changes 2]

If you just want to see changes for a specific release, click the relevant *Added in {XX}* button. For example, to see all new constructors added in JDK 15, click [New > Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/new-list.html#constructor), then click **Added in 15**:

[image: JDK changes 3]

Although the Java Version Almanac has a prettier UI than Javadoc, and it goes all the way back to Java 1.0, I just find the formal Javadoc more convenient to use, and since it is generated directly from the JDK source it is unlikely to contain any errors or omissions.